# React native - dynamically add a view onPress

Tags: javascript, ios, listview, reactjs, react-native

I have a View that contains a button - onPress it opens a modal showing a list of contacts.

1. onPress of any of those contacts (pickContact function) I would like to dynamically add a new View to _renderAddFriendTile (above button).
2. Also ideally, the 'Add' icon next each contact name (in the modal) should update ('Remove' icon) whether or not they are present in _renderAddFriendTile View.

What would be the best way to do it?

**[UPDATED code]**

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react'
    import {
        Text,
        View,
        ListView,
        ScrollView,
        StyleSheet,
        Image,
        TouchableHighlight,
        TextInput,
        Modal,
    } from 'react-native'


    const friends = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    }).cloneWithRows([
        {
            id: 1,
            firstname: 'name01',
            surname: 'surname01',
            image: require('../images/friends/avatar-friend-01.png')
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            firstname: 'name02',
            surname: 'surname02',
            image: require('../images/friends/avatar-friend-02.png')
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            firstname: 'name03',
            surname: 'surname03',
            image: require('../images/friends/avatar-friend-03.png')
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            firstname: 'name04',
            surname: 'surname04',
            image: require('../images/friends/avatar-friend-04.png')
        },
    ])


    class AppView extends Component {
        state = {
            isModalVisible: false,
            contactPicked: [],
            isFriendAdded: false,
        }

        setModalVisible = visible => {
            this.setState({isModalVisible: visible})
        }

        pickContact = (friend) => {
            if(this.state.contactPicked.indexOf(friend) < 0){
                this.setState({
                    contactPicked: [ ...this.state.contactPicked, friend ],

                })
            }

            if(this.state.contactPicked.indexOf(friend) >= 0){
                this.setState({isFriendAdded: true})
            }
        }

        _renderAddFriendTile = () => {
            return(
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={[styles.step, styles.stepAddFriend]}>
                        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.addFriendButtonContainer} onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(true)}}>
                            <View style={styles.addFriendButton}>
                                <Text style={styles.addFriendButtonText}>Add a friend</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }

        render(){
            return (
                <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                    <Modal
                        animationType={'fade'}
                        transparent={true}
                        visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.addFriendModalContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.addFriendModal}>
                                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(false)}}>
                                    <View>
                                        <Text style={{textAlign:'right'}}>Close</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableHighlight>
                                <ListView
                                    dataSource={friends}
                                    renderRow={(friend) => {
                                        return (
                                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.pickContact()}}>
                                                <View style={[styles.row, styles.friendRow]}>
                                                    <Image source={friend.image} style={styles.friendIcon}></Image>
                                                    <Text style={styles.name}>{friend.firstname} </Text>
                                                    <Text style={styles.name}>{friend.surname}</Text>

                                                    <View style={styles.pickContainer}>
                                                        <View style={styles.pickWrapper}>
                                                            <View style={this.state.isFriendAdded ? [styles.buttonActive,styles.buttonSmall]: [styles.buttonInactive,styles.buttonSmall]}>
                                                                <Image source={this.state.isFriendAdded ? require('../images/button-active.png'): require('../images/button-inactive.png')} style={styles.buttonIcon}></Image>
                                                            </View>
                                                        </View>
                                                    </View>
                                                </View>
                                            </TouchableHighlight>
                                        )
                                    }}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>

                    {this._renderAddFriendTile()}
                </ScrollView>
            )
        }
    }

    export default AppView
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you need to update something dynamically, that's a clear indication you need to make use of local state for modelling that data. (Setting aside you are not using a state library management like Redux)

```
state = {
    isModalVisible: false,
    contactPicked: null,
}
```

Your `pickContact` function needs the friend data from the listView, so you need to call it with the row selected:

```
 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.pickContact(friend)}}>
```

Then inside your `pickContact` function, update your UI with the new `contactsPicked` data model

```
pickContact = (friend) => {
    this.setState({
      contactPicked: friend,
    });
}
```

That will make your component re-render and you can place some logic inside `_renderAddFriendTile` to render some extra UI (Views, Texts..) given the existence of value on `this.state.contactPicked` You could use something along these lines:

```
_renderAddFriendTile = () => {
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            {this.state.contactPicked && (
              <View>
                <Text>{contactPicked.firstName}<Text>
              </View>
            )}
            <View style={[styles.step, styles.stepAddFriend]}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.addFriendButtonContainer} onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(true)}}>
                    <View style={styles.addFriendButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.addFriendButtonText}>Add a friend</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Notice you now hold in state the firstName of the contact picked, so point number 2 should be easy to address. Just inside `renderRow` of ListView, render a different Icon if `friend.firstname === this.state.contactPicked.firstname`

Note: Don't rely on firstname for this sort of check since you can have repeated ones and that would fail. The best solution is to provide to your list model an unique `id` property per contact and use that `id` property for checking the logic above.

**Side Notes**

The part `{this.state.contactPicked && (<View><Text>Some text</Text></View)}` is using conditional rendering. The `&&` acts as an *if* so if `this.state.contactPicked` is truthy, it will render the view, otherwise it will render nothing (falsy and `null` values are interpreted by react as "nothing to render").

Of course, if you want to render more than one item dynamically, your state model should be an array instead, i.e `contactsPicked`, being empty initially. Every time you pick a contact you'll add a new contact object to the array. Then inside `_renderAddFriendTile` you can [use map](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components) to dynamically render multiple components. I think you won't need a `ListView`, unless you wanna have a separate scrollable list.

```
_renderAddFriendTile = () => {
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            {this.state.contactsPicked.length && (
              <View>
                {this.state.contactsPicked.map(contact => (
                  <Text>{contact.firstName}</Text>
                )}
              </View>
            )}
            <View style={[styles.step, styles.stepAddFriend]}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.addFriendButtonContainer} onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(true)}}>
                    <View style={styles.addFriendButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.addFriendButtonText}>Add a friend</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you explain the part where you create the View ({this.state.contactPicked && ( <View></View>)}) ? Also what if I wanted to add/increment a new row for each contact pressed on?

Comment: I added a _Side Notes_ section to address those, hope it helps :)

Comment: Any chance you could update your code with the use of array and map (I'm guessing it would use ListView)?

Comment: Great I'll try that. No change needed to be made to setState in pickContact() ?

Comment: Yes, now your model would be an array. You'd need to push new elements (without mutating your model) every time `pickContact` is called. Use `concat` or the spread operator if you are using ES6 to return a new array, like `[ ...this.state.contactsPicked, friend ]`. If the answer was useful for you, I'd appreciate if you could upvote it as well

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I wasn't around. I've updated my code with your latests suggestions. I can now add multiple contacts onPress (if not already added). Now regarding point 2, in state I now have 'isFriendAdded' and inside pickContact() I'm checking if a contact has been added (indexOf) and changing the icon/Image accordingly inside renderRow. But that doesn't work - not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need that extra piece of `state`, since that information could be derived from your existing `contactPicked` state. I'd first only keep the row ids inside `contactPicked` array, instead of the whole object. Then `<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this.pickContact(friend.id)}}>`. In your `pickContact` function, deal with ids and add new ones only.  Finally in your `renderRow` from `ListView` you make the next check when needed: `this.state.contactPicked.indexOf(friend.id) > -1 ? 'remove Button' : 'addButton'`